# Lightfm Incorrect number of features in user_features

Tags: python-3.x, recommendation-engine, lightfm

I am building recommender system - hybrid in Lightfm.
My data has 39326 unique users and 2569 unique game titles(items).
My train interaction sparce matrix has shape: <39326x2569 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 758931 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
My test interaction sparce matrix has shape:<39323x2569 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 194622 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

I train model: model1 = LightFM(learning_rate=0.01, loss='warp')
model1.fit(train_interactions,
epochs=20)
which creates object: <lightfm.lightfm.LightFM at 0x1bf8c8dc4c8>
But when I try to check accuracy by:
train_precision = precision_at_k(model1, train_interactions, k=10).mean()
test_precision = precision_at_k(model1, test_interactions, k=10).mean()

I get error message: Incorrect number of features in user_features
WHY??? Clearly the shapes are compatible? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test sparse matrix is of dimension 39323x2569 while your train sparse matrix is of dimension 39326x2569. You are missing 3 users in your test set.

I suggest you use the lightfm built-in train/test split function to avoid errors : https://making.lyst.com/lightfm/docs/cross_validation.html

If you want to split your data in your own way, you can also transform your user_id and item_id to consecutive integers starting from 0. And then use this :

```
from lightfm.data import Dataset
# Create your train and test set in the format [[user_id1, item_id1, score1], ..., [user_idn, item_idn, scoren]] 
# Your score can be just 1 for an implicit interaction
# user_id and item_id are integers

data = Dataset()
data.fit(unique_user_ids, # list from 0 to n_users 
         unique_item_ids # list from 0 to n_items
        )
train, weights_matrix = data.build_interactions([tuple(i) for i in train])
test, weights_matrix = data.build_interactions([tuple(i) for i in test])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to use my own selection to make sure every user and every item is in train test. So now the shapes are compatible and it works if I don't use any user/item fetaures but when I do I still get error. I added 8 additional features so my shapes are: interactions: 39326x2569, user features shape: 39326 rows × 2577 (2577 = 2569 +8), item features:2569 rows × 39334 columns(39334 = 39326 + 8). It trains fine, but when trying to evaluate it I still get shape error message. What shape should the features be?